# what does $ means in java

Tags: groovy

I'm working in an aplication where there are code lines like this:

```
 Object localObject4 = arrayOfCallSite[6].callGetProperty($get$$class$groovy$lang$Closure());ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(localObject4, $get$$class$groovy$json$JsonDelegate(), clon
```

What does '$' means?

Here is the link of the example:
http://www.javatiger.com/jar.php/1320000/groovy-all-1.8.0

Comment: Java doesn't treat `$` as any special character. But it is used to separate `OuterClass$NestedClass` when you for instance want to print class name, or use class name in `Class.forName("full.name.of.SomeClass")`. But beside that there is no special meaning for it, so you can use it like other characters when while naming your methods or variables. Your question should probably be "what $ represents in groovy?".

Comment: That looks like a class decompiled with the JD decompiler... No human would write code like that plus I don't think that is compilable... The decompiler struggles with Groovy bytecode

Comment: Yes, is a decompiled class, what should I do to get the correct code? is there a chance? @tim_yates make your comment like answer so I can accept it(:

Comment: You could just view the source.https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonDelegate.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a class decompiled with the JD decompiler... No human would write code like that plus I don't think that is compilable... The decompiler struggles with Groovy bytecode

[You could just view the code for that class on github](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonDelegate.java)

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a valid part of an identifier in Java.  This is allowed for example:

```
int $ = 2;
```

Comment: Question `What does '$' means? `, I think I answered it.  If you meant something more like `Why is '$' being used in these Groovy identifiers?' then you should really learn to ask decent questions.